# Connect to a view from a CQWP

Tags: list-view, content-query-web-part, xslt

Is it possible to point the CQWP to a list view? We have implemented 3rd level navigation using subsites and now the subsites can't read the lists in the parent unless we use a content query web part, which in turn requires custom XSLT to get the same built-in views we had with the lists in the parent.

Anyway around this? Can a CQWP point to list views? It would be so convenient! We're so close to using this solution but don't want to do XSLT templates for each list, which already has a view on the parent site.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm open to any other ways you know of pulling list views to show in another site :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the CQWP is configured to find items using a query but won't echo a pre-configured View.

You could however try using a List View web part which will allow you to show a pre-configured view.

Comment: Thanks, GavinB. Can a List View web part pull a list view from another site?

Comment: I wonder if this works for SP2010: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ramg/archive/2009/04/21/implementing-a-simple-cross-site-collection-list-view-webpart.aspx

Comment: I'm pretty sure that list views will work between sites withing the same site collection.